# Какие средства/библиотеки C++ использовать, для рисования простых геометрических фигур (прямые, множества точек) и элементов интерфейса?

Tags: c++

Какие средства/библиотеки C++ можно использовать, для рисования простых геометрических фигур (прямые, множества точек) и создания простых интерфейсных приложений (кнопки, счётчики и т.д.)?

Answer (score 2):

Qt можете использовать. Там есть кнопки, таймеры и тд.
 А для геометрических объектов Opengl. Используйте эту связку qt+opengl.

Answer (score 0):

Можно использовать Windows Forms. Правда, работать придется с C++\CLI. Там есть все элементы управления, которые вы можете увидеть в стандартных приложениях Windows. Рисовать можно с помощью Graphics->Draw'Something'(например, DrawLine).

Также можно использовать SFML, но эта библиотека в основном предназначена для разработки игр.